# Jenkins Periodically Build Triggers does not start on time

Tags: jenkins

We set the build trigger at 9:00AM ( the setting is below ), but sounds like the trigger is not start on time.

Build Triggers > Build periodically

```
00 09 * * 1-5
```

The starting trigger varied a lot

```
9:13 AM
9:54 AM
10:23 AM
```

Is there any log or any clue that we can investigate the cause of this ?

Comment: any chance that your job is triggered at 9, but waits in the queue? (perhaps no available executors)

Comment: Can we trace whether there is an available executor ?

Comment: The job will wait in the build queue if there is no available executor at the time build was triggered. Also check your slave node config if you use one or on master node. Increase the number of executors if you have enough CPU power